# linux, как создать вещание музыки с CD?

Tags: linux, потоки-данных, cd

Подарили cd диск с музыкой, а cd-rom есть только на сервере под ubuntu.
Не могу придумать как послушать диск. Cd-rom примонтировал, диск расшарил через самба, но на диске дорожки, соответственно папка пуста.

Интересно, конечно, застримить и поймать под виндой через VLC например, но главное чтобы музыка заиграла и не важно как, может как-то сграбить диск можно.

Проблема в том, что иксов на сервере нет, ни какие gui не поддерживаются. Только ssh и samba.

CD-rom снять не могу, т.к. IDE нигде нет, только на сервере.

интересуют любые варианты, как это возможно?

Comment: Найти любую граббилку Audio CD, сграббить и скачать себе wav с сервера?

Comment: @andreymal, вот я и не могу найти без gui, консольную.

Comment: @Skit, например, [cdparanoia](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=cdparanoia&searchon=names&exact=1&suite=all&section=all).

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, да, с ее помощью получился прекрасный рип!

Answer (score 2):

например, с помощью [*mpd*](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=mpd&searchon=names&exact=1&suite=all&section=all):

1. можно [воспроизвести cdda каким-нибудь из предложенных способов](http://mpd.wikia.com/wiki/How_to_play_an_audio_cdrom)
2. и «раздать» звук [по сети с помощью встроенного в *mpd* http streaming сервера](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Music_Player_Daemon/Tips_and_tricks#HTTP_Streaming)

Comment: по первой ссылке рипперы. Половина сделана, рип снят. Остается непонятным, как воспроизвести диск непосредственно на сервере. С mpd понятно, он отправит то, что будет воспроизведено. Думаю pulseaudio должен работать без gui, разберусь как разбить рип на дорожки и попробую. Спасибо за наводку!

Comment: Аудио диск преобразован в мп3. Не понятно как вещает mpd. Запускаю mplayer, втыкаю в гнездо наушники - звук есть. Запускаю mpd, ссылку не открывает, хотя сервис запущен,  нет стат показывает два порта 6600 и 8000. В конфиге указывается папка с музыкой, mpd сам воспроизводит?

Comment: 6600 — обычно это порт для управления. если сконфигурировали mpd для прослушивания внешнего адреса (не localhost), то можете подключаться [каким-нибудь клиентом](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Music_Player_Daemon#.D0.9A.D0.BB.D0.B8.D0.B5.D0.BD.D1.82.D1.8B) по сети и управлять.

Comment: @Skit, могу поделиться рабочим конфигом mpd.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, готово.

Answer (score 1):

Болванка снимается обычным `dd`, под виндой монтируется как диск чем-нибудь вроде [WinCDEmu](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/WinCDEmu) и скармливается [Exact Audio Copy](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_Audio_Copy).

Если хочется стримить через `mpd` - вот рабочий конфиг:

```
    # An example configuration file for MPD
# See the mpd.conf man page for a more detailed description of each parameter.


# Files and directories #######################################################
#
# This setting controls the top directory which MPD will search to discover the
# available audio files and add them to the daemon's online database. This 
# setting defaults to the XDG directory, otherwise the music directory will be
# be disabled and audio files will only be accepted over ipc socket (using
# file:// protocol) or streaming files over an accepted protocol.
#
music_directory     "/var/lib/mpd/music"
#
# This setting sets the MPD internal playlist directory. The purpose of this
# directory is storage for playlists created by MPD. The server will use 
# playlist files not created by the server but only if they are in the MPD
# format. This setting defaults to playlist saving being disabled.
#
playlist_directory      "/var/lib/mpd/playlists"
#
# This setting sets the location of the MPD database. This file is used to
# load the database at server start up and store the database while the 
# server is not up. This setting defaults to disabled which will allow
# MPD to accept files over ipc socket (using file:// protocol) or streaming
# files over an accepted protocol.
#
db_file         "/var/lib/mpd/tag_cache"
# 
# These settings are the locations for the daemon log files for the daemon.
# These logs are great for troubleshooting, depending on your log_level
# settings.
#
# The special value "syslog" makes MPD use the local syslog daemon. This
# setting defaults to logging to syslog, otherwise logging is disabled.
#
log_file            "/var/log/mpd/mpd.log"
#
# This setting sets the location of the file which stores the process ID
# for use of mpd --kill and some init scripts. This setting is disabled by
# default and the pid file will not be stored.
#
pid_file            "/var/run/mpd/pid"
#
# This setting sets the location of the file which contains information about
# most variables to get MPD back into the same general shape it was in before
# it was brought down. This setting is disabled by default and the server 
# state will be reset on server start up.
#
state_file          "/var/lib/mpd/state"
#
# The location of the sticker database.  This is a database which
# manages dynamic information attached to songs.
#
sticker_file                   "/var/lib/mpd/sticker.sql"
#
###############################################################################


# General music daemon options ################################################
#
# This setting specifies the user that MPD will run as. MPD should never run as
# root and you may use this setting to make MPD change its user ID after
# initialization. This setting is disabled by default and MPD is run as the
# current user.
#
user                "mpd"
#
# This setting specifies the group that MPD will run as. If not specified
# primary group of user specified with "user" setting will be used (if set).
# This is useful if MPD needs to be a member of group such as "audio" to
# have permission to use sound card.
#
#group                          "nogroup"
#
# This setting sets the address for the daemon to listen on. Careful attention
# should be paid if this is assigned to anything other then the default, any.
# This setting can deny access to control of the daemon. Choose any if you want
# to have mpd listen on every address
#
# For network

#!!!
bind_to_address             "localhost"
#bind_to_address            "0.0.0.0"

#
# And for Unix Socket
#bind_to_address        "/var/run/mpd/socket"
#
# This setting is the TCP port that is desired for the daemon to get assigned
# to.
#
#port               "6600"
#
# This setting controls the type of information which is logged. Available 
# setting arguments are "default", "secure" or "verbose". The "verbose" setting
# argument is recommended for troubleshooting, though can quickly stretch
# available resources on limited hardware storage.
#
#log_level          "default"
#
# If you have a problem with your MP3s ending abruptly it is recommended that 
# you set this argument to "no" to attempt to fix the problem. If this solves
# the problem, it is highly recommended to fix the MP3 files with vbrfix
# (available as vbrfix in the debian archive), at which
# point gapless MP3 playback can be enabled.
#
#gapless_mp3_playback           "yes"
#
# This setting enables MPD to create playlists in a format usable by other
# music players.
#
#save_absolute_paths_in_playlists   "no"
#
# This setting defines a list of tag types that will be extracted during the 
# audio file discovery process. Optionally, 'comment' can be added to this
# list.
#
#metadata_to_use    "artist,album,title,track,name,genre,date,composer,performer,disc"
#
# This setting enables automatic update of MPD's database when files in 
# music_directory are changed.
#
#auto_update    "yes"
#
# Limit the depth of the directories being watched, 0 means only watch
# the music directory itself.  There is no limit by default.
#
#auto_update_depth "3"
#
###############################################################################


# Symbolic link behavior ######################################################
#
# If this setting is set to "yes", MPD will discover audio files by following 
# symbolic links outside of the configured music_directory.
#
#follow_outside_symlinks    "yes"
#
# If this setting is set to "yes", MPD will discover audio files by following
# symbolic links inside of the configured music_directory.
#
#follow_inside_symlinks     "yes"
#
###############################################################################


# Zeroconf / Avahi Service Discovery ##########################################
#
# If this setting is set to "yes", service information will be published with
# Zeroconf / Avahi.
#
zeroconf_enabled        "yes"
#
# The argument to this setting will be the Zeroconf / Avahi unique name for
# this MPD server on the network.
#
zeroconf_name           "mpd@linux"
#
###############################################################################


# Permissions #################################################################
#
# If this setting is set, MPD will require password authorization. The password
# can setting can be specified multiple times for different password profiles.
#

# !!!
#password                        "password@read,add,control,admin"

#
# This setting specifies the permissions a user has who has not yet logged in. 
#
#default_permissions             "read,add,control,admin"
#
###############################################################################


# Input #######################################################################
#

#input {
#       plugin "curl"
#       proxy "http://proxy:3128"
#       proxy_user "user"
#       proxy_password "password"
#}

#
###############################################################################

# Audio Output ################################################################
#
# MPD supports various audio output types, as well as playing through multiple 
# audio outputs at the same time, through multiple audio_output settings 
# blocks. Setting this block is optional, though the server will only attempt
# autodetection for one sound card.
#
# See <http://mpd.wikia.com/wiki/Configuration#Audio_Outputs> for examples of 
# other audio outputs.
#
# An example of an ALSA output:
#
audio_output {
    type        "alsa"
    name        "My ALSA Device"
    device      "hw:0,0"    # optional
    format      "44100:16:2"    # optional
    mixer_device    "default"   # optional
    mixer_control   "PCM"       # optional
    mixer_index "0"     # optional
}
#
# An example of an OSS output:
#
#audio_output {
#   type        "oss"
#   name        "My OSS Device"
#   device      "/dev/dsp"  # optional
#   format      "44100:16:2"    # optional
#   mixer_device    "/dev/mixer"    # optional
#   mixer_control   "PCM"       # optional
#}
#
# An example of a shout output (for streaming to Icecast):
#
audio_output {
    type        "shout"
    encoding    "ogg"           # optional
    name        "Cool music"
    host        "localhost"
    port        "8000"
    mount       "/mpd.ogg"
    password    "MyPassword"
    quality     "5.0"
#   bitrate     "128"
    format      "44100:16:1"
    protocol    "icecast2"      # optional
#   user        "source"        # optional
    description "Rock-n-roll is alive!" # optional
#   genre       "none"          # optional
    public      "yes"           # optional
#   timeout     "2"         # optional
}
#
# An example of a recorder output:
#
#audio_output {
#       type            "recorder"
#       name            "My recorder"
#       encoder         "vorbis"                # optional, vorbis or lame
#       path            "/var/lib/mpd/recorder/mpd.ogg"
##      quality         "5.0"                   # do not define if bitrate is defined
#       bitrate         "128"                   # do not define if quality is defined
#       format          "44100:16:1"
#}
#
# An example of a httpd output (built-in HTTP streaming server):
#
audio_output {
    type        "httpd"
    name        "Cosy little radio"
    genre       "Rock-n-roll, rock, blues"
    website     "http://localhost/music"
    encoder     "lame"          # optional, vorbis or lame
    port        "1968"
#   quality     "5.0"           # do not define if bitrate is defined
    bitrate     "128"           # do not define if quality is defined
    format      "44100:16:1"
}
#
# An example of a pulseaudio output (streaming to a remote pulseaudio server)
#
#audio_output {
#   type        "pulse"
#   name        "My Pulse Output"
#   server      "remote_server"     # optional
#   sink        "remote_server_sink"    # optional
#}
#
## Example "pipe" output:
#
#audio_output {
#   type        "pipe"
#   name        "my pipe"
#   command     "aplay -f cd 2>/dev/null"
## Or if you're want to use AudioCompress
#   command     "AudioCompress -m | aplay -f cd 2>/dev/null"
## Or to send raw PCM stream through PCM:
#   command     "nc example.org 8765"
#   format      "44100:16:2"
#}
#
## An example of a null output (for no audio output):
#
#audio_output {
#   type        "null"
#   name        "My Null Output"
#}
#
# This setting will change all decoded audio to be converted to the specified
# format before being passed to the audio outputs. By default, this setting is
# disabled.
#
#audio_output_format        "44100:16:2"
#
# If MPD has been compiled with libsamplerate support, this setting specifies 
# the sample rate converter to use.  Possible values can be found in the 
# mpd.conf man page or the libsamplerate documentation. By default, this is
# setting is disabled.
#
#samplerate_converter       "Fastest Sinc Interpolator"
#
###############################################################################


# Volume control mixer ########################################################
#
# These are the global volume control settings. By default, this setting will
# be detected to the available audio output device, with preference going to 
# hardware mixing. Hardware and software mixers for individual audio_output
# sections cannot yet be mixed.
#
# An example for controlling an ALSA, OSS or Pulseaudio mixer; If this
# setting is used other sound applications will be affected by the volume
# being controlled by MPD.
#
#mixer_type         "hardware"
#
# An example for controlling all mixers through software. This will control
# all controls, even if the mixer is not supported by the device and will not
# affect any other sound producing applications.
#
mixer_type          "software"
#
# This example will not allow MPD to touch the mixer at all and will disable
# all volume controls.
#
#mixer_type         "disabled"
#
###############################################################################


# Normalization automatic volume adjustments ##################################
#
# This setting specifies the type of ReplayGain to use. This setting can have
# the argument "album" or "track". See <http://www.replaygain.org> for more
# details. This setting is disabled by default.
#
#replaygain         "album"
#
# This setting sets the pre-amp used for files that have ReplayGain tags. By
# default this setting is disabled.
#
#replaygain_preamp      "0"
#
# This setting enables on-the-fly normalization volume adjustment. This will
# result in the volume of all playing audio to be adjusted so the output has 
# equal "loudness". This setting is disabled by default.
#
#volume_normalization       "no"
#
###############################################################################


# MPD Internal Buffering ######################################################
#
# This setting adjusts the size of internal decoded audio buffering. Changing
# this may have undesired effects. Don't change this if you don't know what you
# are doing.
#
#audio_buffer_size      "2048"
#
# This setting controls the percentage of the buffer which is filled before 
# beginning to play. Increasing this reduces the chance of audio file skipping, 
# at the cost of increased time prior to audio playback.
#
#buffer_before_play     "10%"
#
###############################################################################


# Resource Limitations ########################################################
#
# These settings are various limitations to prevent MPD from using too many
# resources. Generally, these settings should be minimized to prevent security
# risks, depending on the operating resources.
#
#connection_timeout     "60"
#max_connections        "10"
#max_playlist_length        "16384"
#max_command_list_size      "2048"
#max_output_buffer_size     "8192"
#
###############################################################################


# Character Encoding ##########################################################
#
# If file or directory names do not display correctly for your locale then you 
# may need to modify this setting. After modification of this setting mpd 
# --create-db must be run to change the database.
#
filesystem_charset      "UTF-8"
#
# This setting controls the encoding that ID3v1 tags should be converted from.
#
id3v1_encoding          "UTF-8"
#
###############################################################################
# SIDPlay decoder #############################################################
#
# songlength_database:
#  Location of your songlengths file, as distributed with the HVSC.
#  The sidplay plugin checks this for matching MD5 fingerprints.
#  See http://www.c64.org/HVSC/DOCUMENTS/Songlengths.faq
#
# default_songlength:
#  This is the default playing time in seconds for songs not in the
#  songlength database, or in case you're not using a database.
#  A value of 0 means play indefinitely.
#
# filter:
#  Turns the SID filter emulation on or off.
#
#decoder {
#       plugin                  "sidplay"
#       songlength_database     "/media/C64Music/DOCUMENTS/Songlengths.txt"
#       default_songlength      "120"
#       filter "true"
#}
#
###############################################################################
```

Посли вливания конфига (бэкап своего всё равно сделай) звук будет транслиться по адресу `http://linux-server-with-mpd:1968`. Его можно уже скармливать mplayer, vlc, кому угодно.
Для управления на сервере можно поставить `ncmpcpp`.

Comment: вы говорите про windows?

Comment: @Skit, ну да. Образ снимается через линуксовую утилиту `dd`, а потом монитруется и грабится уже на windows. Можно всё сделать на linux, но это уже вопрос привычки и удобства.

Comment: @donRumata, *снимается обычным dd* — програм `cp` ещё более «обычна», и (для копирования блочного устройства) её применение отличается от `dd` «всего лишь» более простым синтаксисом вызова. // **но** я не уверен, что для «копирования» cdda подойдёт хоть одна из них, ведь к cdda, насколько мне известно, нет интерфейса блочного устройства. для сохранения аудидорожек нужна программа-«риппер». впрочем, в gnu/linux таких программ более чем достаточно. начиная с самой, наверно, древней — cdparanoia.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, не знал. Надо при случае попробовать.

Comment: @donRumata, а зачем в приведённом конфиге аж три output-а? целых два для сетевого вещания и один (через alsa) — для локального воспроизведения (он-то в ситуации автора вопроса точно излишен).

Comment: ага, разобрался. Там для mpd нужен еще и клиент, я поставил mpc, который уже запускает воспроизведение. Сколько раз читал, что ставят клиента, столько раз мимо ушей пропустил ))

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, ну потому что конфиг привёл как есть. 2 сетевых, потому что 1 вещает в айскаст, а второй - самим mpd. Следы эксперементов, которые не закаментил.

Comment: @Skit, я написал про `ncmpcpp`.

Comment: ясно, ясно. Везде пишут "управление mpd", а мне зачем им управлять? )) Я думал, раз папка с музыкой указана, значит он сам ее воспроизводит, а оказалось, что плэй делает клиент mpd: mpc, ncmcpp или другой.

Comment: @Skit, ну так заработало или нет? Если да - отметь как правильный.